# Template literals as string content in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, template-literals

I'm wondering whats the best practice for strings values mixed with variables inside JSX tags, I've listed the options I'm familiar with:

```
render() {
    const {totalCount} = this.state;
    const totalCountStr = `Total count: ${totalCount}`;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Total count: {totalCount}</h1> // 1
            <h1>`Total count: ${totalCount}`</h1> // 2
            <h1>{totalCountStr}</h1> // 3
        </div>
    );
}
```

What's the best practice or the use cases to use them differently?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think #2 works. You could inline #3, but it would be very unappealing, especially compared to #1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Template literals aren't supported by React JSX currently. The correct way to do it is like so:

```
<h1>Total count: {this.state.totalCount}</h1>
```

**Edit:** Your third way is also correct, but I personally wouldn't recommend it because of debug issues as you would need to scan for brackets as the code expands

```
<h1>{`Total count: ${this.state.totalCount}`}</h1>
```

Comment: You probably could do ``<h1>{ `Total count: ${totalCount}` }</h1>`` though

Comment: @Bergi Kinda a hack though. Definitely will add it to my answer

Comment: I wonder what would be neccesary to support backticks in attributes in jsx